# How to solve these equations numerically?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerics

I have some differential equations as below. I have tried to solve them numerically with `NDSolve`:

```
cf = 200000000;
α = .7;
r = 0.4;
FSR = Pi (cf/500);
g0 = 1;
g1[t_] := g0 (Sin[t/τ]);
g2[t_] := -g0 (Cos[t/τ]);
γc1 = 000 Pi;
γc2 = 000 Pi;
γf = 44000 Pi;
τ = 1;
ξi = {{Re[α]}, {Im[α]}};
ai = 1/4 {{E^(-2 r), 0}, {0, E^(2 r)}};
γ1 = (2 γf (g1[t])^2)/FSR;
γ2 = (2 γf (g2[t])^2)/FSR;
γ12 = (2 γf (g1[t]) (g2[t]))/FSR;
sol1 = NDSolve[{Derivative[1][m1][
 t] == (-γc1 + γ1/2) (m1[t]) - 
 g1[t] (f0[t]) - (γ12/2) (m2[t]), 
 Derivative[1][f0][
 t] == -((γf/2) f0[t] + g1[t] (m1[t]) + g2[t] (m2[t])), 
 Derivative[1][m2][t] == (-γc2 + γ2/2) (m2[t]) - 
 g2[t] (f0[t]) - (γ12/2) (m1[t]), m1[0] == 1, f0[0] == 0, 
 m2[0] == 0}, {m1, m2, f0}, {t, 0, (Pi/2) τ}]

 MM[t_] = Evaluate[m2[t] /. sol1[[1]]]
 ans = MM[1.57]
```

As one can see, the final answer is a number. The question is, how can I solve these equations for a variety of values in `FSR = Pi (cf/500)`? The above is for just `500` but I want to have `MM[t_]` for `FSR = Pi (cf/L)` where `L=100,110,120,...,500`. Note that in each case, the final value of the `t` (after solving the set of equations) should be equal to `\pi/2=1.57`.

Thank U for helping.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue) instead, and change the target function from `{m1, m2, f0}` to just `m2[Pi/2]`:

```
FSR = Pi cf/L;
γ1 = (2 γf (g1[t])^2)/FSR;
γ2 = (2 γf (g2[t])^2)/FSR;
γ12 = (2 γf (g1[t]) (g2[t]))/FSR;

sol1 = ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {
    m1'[t]==(-γc1+γ1/2) m1[t]-g1[t] f0[t]-(γ12/2) m2[t],
    f0'[t]==-((γf/2) f0[t]+g1[t] m1[t]+g2[t] m2[t]),
    m2'[t]==(-γc2+γ2/2) m2[t]-g2[t] f0[t]-(γ12/2) m1[t],
    m1[0]==1,
    f0[0]==0,
    m2[0]==0
    },
    m2[Pi/2],
    {t,0,(Pi/2) τ},
    L
];
```

Then:

```
Table[sol1[t], {t, 100, 500, 10}]
```

> {0.0110884, 0.0122086, 0.0133307, 0.0144548, 0.0155808, 0.0167088, 0.0178388, 0.0189707, 0.0201046, 0.0212405, 0.0223783, 0.0235181, 0.0246599, 0.0258037, 0.0269495, 0.0280973, 0.0292471, 0.0303988, 0.0315526, 0.0327085, 0.0338663, 0.0350262, 0.0361881, 0.037352, 0.038518, 0.039686, 0.0408561, 0.0420282, 0.0432023, 0.0443786, 0.0455569, 0.0467372, 0.0479197, 0.0491042, 0.0502907, 0.0514794, 0.0526702, 0.053863, 0.055058, 0.0562551, 0.0574542}

Comment: Thank U for Ur answer, but I cannot have these numbers! The output is some `{ParametricFunctions}`!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for

```
cf = 200000000;
α = .7;
r = 0.4;
g0 = 1;
g1[t_] := g0 Sin[t/τ];
g2[t_] := -g0 Cos[t/τ];
γc1 = 000 Pi;
γc2 = 000 Pi;
γf = 44000 Pi;
τ = 1;
ξi = {{Re[α]}, {Im[α]}};
ai = 1/4 {{E^(-2 r), 0}, {0, E^(2 r)}};
Table[
 FSR = Pi cf/L;
 γ1 = 2 γf g1[t]^2/FSR;
 γ2 = 2 γf g2[t]^2/FSR;
 γ12 = 2 γf g1[t] g2[t]/FSR; 
 sol1 = NDSolve[{
    m1'[t] == (-γc1 + γ1/2) m1[t] - g1[t] f0[t] - γ12/2 m2[t], 
    f0'[t] == -(γf/2 f0[t] + g1[t] m1[t] + g2[t] m2[t]), 
    m2'[t] == (-γc2 + γ2/2) m2[t] - g2[t] f0[t] - γ12/2 m1[t],
    m1[0] == 1, f0[0] == 0, m2[0] == 0}, {m1, m2, f0}, {t, 0, Pi/2 τ}]; 
 MM[t_] = Evaluate[m2[t] /. sol1[[1]]]; MM[Pi/2], {L, 100, 500, 100}]
```

which gives you `{0.0110884, 0.0223783, 0.0338663, 0.0455569, 0.0574542}` for the 5 values of L.

Your `γc1 = 000 Pi; γc2 = 000 Pi;` worry me. Are those perhaps typos?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function of two variables

```
cf = 200000000;
\[Alpha] = .7;
r = 0.4;
FSR = Pi (cf/L);
g0 = 1;
g1[t_] := g0 (Sin[t/\[Tau]]);
g2[t_] := -g0 (Cos[t/\[Tau]]);
\[Gamma]c1 = 000 Pi;
\[Gamma]c2 = 000 Pi;
\[Gamma]f = 44000 Pi;
\[Tau] = 1;
\[Xi]i = {{Re[\[Alpha]]}, {Im[\[Alpha]]}};
ai = 1/4 {{E^(-2 r), 0}, {0, E^(2 r)}};
\[Gamma]1 = (2 \[Gamma]f (g1[t])^2)/FSR;
\[Gamma]2 = (2 \[Gamma]f (g2[t])^2)/FSR;
\[Gamma]12 = (2 \[Gamma]f (g1[t]) (g2[t]))/FSR;
sol1 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{Derivative[1][m1][
      t] == (-\[Gamma]c1 + \[Gamma]1/2) (m1[t]) - 
      g1[t] (f0[t]) - (\[Gamma]12/2) (m2[t]), 
    Derivative[1][f0][
      t] == -((\[Gamma]f/2) f0[t] + g1[t] (m1[t]) + g2[t] (m2[t])), 
    Derivative[1][m2][t] == (-\[Gamma]c2 + \[Gamma]2/2) (m2[t]) - 
      g2[t] (f0[t]) - (\[Gamma]12/2) (m1[t]), m1[0] == 1, f0[0] == 0, 
    m2[0] == 0}, m2, {t, 0, (Pi/2) \[Tau]}, {L}];

MM[L_, t_] := sol1[L][t]
ans = MM[100, 1.57]
0.0110884
```